# Removing tab colouring in MacVim

Tags: vim, macvim

I am new to using Vim/MacVim environments and under a pre-existing configuration handed to me by a friend (sort of a newbie-starter-kit), there is a marked tab character which has not been followed with a piece of code, as can be seen in the screenshot below. Which option in Vim can be used to remove this effect?

Thanks in advance for the help.

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

Comment: Could you post the content of the colorscheme you are using? If you don't know its name type `:verbose colorscheme` then [enter].

Comment: This kind of tab highlighting could be accomplished by adding a specific highlight group (:highlight) and matching (:match) this group to tabs followed by whitespace in your vimrc file. See [this](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Highlight_unwanted_spaces) page for information on highlighting whitespace.
Perhaps it will tell you what to look for in your vimrc file and you can try deleting that section and check if that has any effect on the highlighting of tabs.

Answer (score 0):

The following will reveal the syntax group that colors the tab in such a way:

Put the cursor on the marked tab, then do the following:

```
:echo synIDattr(synID(line("."),col("."),1),"name")
```

It will show you the syntax group of the current character under the cursor. Then you can use the following to show the color assignment:

```
:hi <ouput from previous command>
```

From there you can start searching where in the vim config files the syntax and highlighting are assigned.